# Espresso.pressBack twice not working

Tags: android, android-view, android-espresso

I have an android application under test which has three views, view1, view2, view3.

Using my espresso test I click on some item in view1 which opens view2 and then I click on listItem in view2 which opens view3. After verifying necessary information on view3, I press back Espresso.pressback() twice to come back to the view1 but during test execution I see that probably Espresso.pressBack is executed only once and view remains on view2.

During debug everything works smooth and view1 is opened when Espresso.pressBack() is executed twice.

Any idea what is happening or how to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to add some sleep between the two pressBack() calls? This might give you a clue.

Comment: Yes I had added sleep and with that test was passing so looks like view2 takes a bit time to load completely however because espresso should take care of wait till view is loaded and I am wondering why it is not doing so in this case.

Comment: It seems that espresso does not wait until next activity to be resumed to proceed to next action https://github.com/misyobun/android-test-kit/issues/55